# State возвращает предыдущее значение

Tags: reactjs

Прошу помощи: используя useEffect посылаю 2 запроса и полученные url(случайные фото собак) записываю в стейты randomOne и randomTwo. Потом при помощи рег.выражения извлекаю из этих url строку(породы собак) и хочу записать в стейт breed. Но в breed записываются предыдущие значения, а не новые. Я так понимаю, что это происходит из-за отложенного обновления стейтов? И как это исправить?

```
function App() {
  const [randomOne, setRandomOne] = useState()
  const [randomTwo, setRandomTwo] = useState()
  const [breed, setBreed] = useState([])
  const regexp = /\/+/g

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
          setRandomOne(data.message)
       }) 
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
         .then(data => data.json())
         .then(data => {
            setRandomTwo(data.message)
        })
         setBreed([randomOne.split(regexp)[3], randomTwo.split(regexp)[3]])
  }, [])
```

Comment: либо испольтзуйте `useEffect(() => {}, [randomOne, randomTwo])` , либо `fetch` засуньте в `.then` и там записывайте данные в `randomOne, randomTwo, breed`. Но первый вариант посолдинее будет.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит использовать `useEffect` с зависимостями `randomOne, randomTwo`. Он будет вызван, когда значения этих переменных изменятся. Соответственно, нам надо изменять `breed` при условии, что `randomOne` и `randomTwo` уже получены - поэтому просто добавляем проверку.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [randomOne, setRandomOne] = useState();
  const [randomTwo, setRandomTwo] = useState();
  const [breed, setBreed] = useState([]);
  const regexp = /\/+/g;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setRandomOne(data.message));
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setRandomTwo(data.message));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (randomOne && randomTwo) {
      console.log(randomOne);
      setBreed([randomOne.split(regexp)[3], randomTwo.split(regexp)[3]]);
    }
  }, [randomOne, randomTwo]);

  return <div>{breed.length > 0 && breed.map((e) => <p key={e}>{e}</p>)}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!